# Как проверить перекодировалась ли строка?

Tags: c#, qr

Подскажите, как проверить перекодировался ли текст. Пытался вывести перекодированный текст так:

```
MessageBox.Show(text);
```

но на выходе просто тот же текст только не понятно в какой кодировке.

```
string text = textBox1.Text;
var utf8 = Encoding.UTF8;
byte[] utfBytes = utf8.GetBytes(text);
text = utf8.GetString(utfBytes, 0, utfBytes.Length);
```

Comment: Понятие «кодировка» имеет смысл для строки, представленной в виде набора байт, а не для строки самой по себе.

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 3):

Строки (System.String) в .NET все представляют собой Unicode последовательности символов. То есть в рантайме мы имеем в переменной универсальное значение строки.

Сложнее, если мы хотим это представление где-то сохранить, или откуда-то прочитать. Для этого нам необходимо привести строку к набору байтов (сериализовать), или из набора байтов получить строку (в которой все символы правильные).

То есть всё, что делает приведенный выше код - берет строку, приводит её к набору байтов, соответствующему кодировке UTF8 и затем этот набор байтов преобразует обратно к той же строке. То есть он не делает вообще никакой перекодировки.

"Перекодирование" на самом деле представляет собой перевод набора байтов из одной кодировки, в другую. То есть берем набор байтов в кодировке UTF8 и переводим его в набор байтов в кодировке CP1251.

Дополнительно, для просветвления, можно прочитать [статью Джоеля Спольски про строки](http://russian.joelonsoftware.com/Articles/BacktoBasics.html).